# Problems with booting same Linux installation on both physical System and VM for dual use

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtual-machine, uefi, bootable

The question basically boils down to "how does a Linux installation need to be setup in order to be able to do boot from both VM and the physical machine?"

I try to achieve 2 goals with this that basically share similar Problems:

1. I'd like to be able to install most common distros from VM to physical disk in UEFI mode, instead of making a bootable installer USB, because it's way more convenient and also safer(the installer only has access to that one drive i pass through).
2. I'd like to use the OS both booted on physical machine and inside a VM from windows.

*Setup:* I pass a NVMe hard drive with GPT in Virtualbox with Vboxmanage command and disable the drive in Windows disk management so it doesn't crash when partitioning inside of VM, and install from ISO. Tried the same in Hyper-V with same results, which is actually easier to set up.

There are some scenarios where this just works out of the box:
Ubuntu/Kubuntu installs fine in BIOS and UEFI mode and boots in both ways easily when choosing automatic partitioning.
EndavourOS Cassini installed fine on a SATA ssd in BIOS mode and could be used both ways.

I'd prefer to use UEFI mode because i want to install several OS with manual partitioning and shared home and assume that works better with a EFI system partition + rEFInd.

*problems i'm trying to solve:*
Kubuntu doesn't boot outside VM when specifying the ESP manually as it can't mount the root drive, also when trying to boot with rEFInd. EndeavourOS Artemis Nova doesn't find root drive outside VM no matter how the partitioning is chosen in UEFI mode, same with openSUSE tumbleweed it seems. I can use the instructions here: [Archwiki Moving existing install out of VM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Moving_an_existing_install_into_(or_out_of)_a_virtual_machine), but then it won't boot inside the VM anymore, purpose defeated...

EndeavourOS Installed in BIOS mode is stuck forever in `a starting job is running for /dev/disk/by-UUID/{root drive UUID}` outside of VM, the UUIDs in the fstab are correct, i checked both in vm and from a working physical install
Could there be a problem with the device naming here as the installer sees the NVMe as sda but on the real system it's nvme1n1? Ubuntu doesn't seem to have a problem with it.

If you think it could help to provide more tests/information please tell me. Thank you very much for any input on the matter!